# typeerror while using rename function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i tried to rename a column in a Dataframe by using rename function
but I get an error indicates: `"builtins.TypeError: rename() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'"`

my code is :

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime as dt

#this is latest 5 days data selection
prev=30
endDate=dt.datetime.today().date()
startDate=endDate-pd.to_timedelta(prev,unit='d')


def get_data(ticker):
    stockData=web.DataReader(ticker,'yahoo',startDate,endDate)['Adj Close']
    stockData.rename(columns={'Adj Close':str(ticker)},inplace=True)
    return stockData
TSLA=get_data('TSLA')
VTI=get_data('VTI')
```

I wonder why it happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Series.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html) does not have a `columns` argument. Series are 1D so there is only ever one thing to rename. On the other hand, [`DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) does have a `columns` argument, since there can be multiple columns to rename

---

Either select the DataFrame slice `[[ ]]`:

```
stockData = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', startDate, endDate)[['Adj Close']]
stockData.rename(columns={'Adj Close': str(ticker)}, inplace=True)
```

or rename the Series:

```
stockData = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', startDate, endDate)['Adj Close']
stockData.rename(str(ticker), inplace=True)
```